# Is it possible to avoid a global here? And is it worth it?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kendo-ui

I have a web application that displays a google map. When a user clicks somewhere on a polygon on the map, a kendo grid on the same page is populate via an ajax call that a kendo datasource repesents.

When data are fetched by the kendo grid, I also use the same data to populate a tooltip on the google map. This tooltip needs to be displayed at the same place where user clicked.

In order to pass the coordinates of this click I'm using a global variable. *I would like to know if it's possible to avoid it, and also if it's worth the trouble.*

Here are excerpts from my code.

Define the global:

```
var clickLatLng;
```

Subscribe for the click event on the map:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function(event) {
    //Keep track of coordinates in a global
    clickLatLng = event.latLng;

    // initiate the ajax call to get the data
    dataSource.read(this.objInfo.id);

    // update grid view
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
    grid.refresh();
});
```

Define the datasource:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/getdata",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: function (response) {
            var events = [];

            var eventList = response.EventList;
            if (!eventList) {
                return events;
            }

            // This fills events from eventList
            populateEvents(events, eventList);

            // see below
            setToolTipValues(events);

            return events;
        },
        ...
    }
});
```

Display the tooltip:

```
var setToolTipValues = function (events) {
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infoWindow.setContent(getTooltipConent(events));
    // here we use the global saved earlier to display the tooltip at the correct coordinates
    infoWindow.setPosition({ lat: clickLatLng.lat(), lng: clickLatLng.lng() });
    // map is also global I'm guessing there is no work around that
    infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

**Update**: to add some more information, the code above is located in pageHelper.js
pageHelper.js looks like this:

```
var pageHelper = function($, google, model) {

    var clickLatLng;
    ...    
}
```

And this is how it's called from the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var model = ...;  //the ... bit comes from the server
    pageHelper($, google, model);
</script>
```

**Update 2**
Sequence of events:

- User clicks a poligon
- `google.maps.event.addListener(polygon` bit of code fires
- it calls `dataSource.read` which initiate the ajax call
- when the ajax call is finished `data: function (response) {` is fired
- It calls `setToolTipValues` to display the tooltip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store a value for later consumption by other events, you have several choices which are not globals:

1. You can create a common closure (usually an IIFE) containing all code that needs to access the value and store the value in a local variable in the closure.
2. You can store the value as a property of some existing object that all code that needs to use that value can access.  This could be a DOM object or some other object you have in your code.  jQuery's `.data()` provides a simple way to associate a value with a DOM object without using a global.
3. You can create a single global namespace object and put your value on that single namespace object as a property.  While this uses a global, it allows you to have many global properties while only consuming one single name in the global namespace.
4. If the value is being used as all part of one main event trigger, then you can usually find a way to pass the variable along so other pieces of the event handling can use the original value rather than storing it in a global.  I can't tell the exact sequence of events in your code to know whether this is possible or not.

In general, it is a good idea to avoid globals for a variety of reasons.  It isn't a hard rule, but it is a guideline that is considered generally good practice.  If you find a need for multiple globals, you can also use a single global namespace object (this is what frameworks like jQuery do) so you're only creating one new globally accessible symbol.

---

**Update based on some clarification from the OP:**

It sounds like you already aren't storing it in a global at all, but rather it's in a local variable in a closure.  That's probably all you need to do as there really isn't a whole lot of advantage to storing it somewhere else.

Because you want to use the value in a method that is called indirectly by some other part of the system, you can't directly pass the value along as just function arguments, so the typical Javascript solution to this is to store it in a parent closure where you can then access it from the callback function when that is called later.  That's the usual Javascript design pattern for this type of problem.

So, if this understanding is correct:

1. User clicks polygon.
2. You read data from the data source.
3. The `schema.data` method in the data source is called by the kendo framework as part of reading from that data source.
4. You need to use the click location in that `schema.data` callback.

Then, the best you can do here is to put the value in a parent closure where that `scheme.data` callback can get to the original click location.

---

I might personally make one change to the way your code is structured.  I'd probably pass the position into `setToolTipValues()` as an argument and fetch the closure variable to pass to it inside of `schema.data()`.  This makes `setToolTipValues()` independent of how the location was obtained and keeps the dependency on this closure variable in the one place it can't be avoided.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I added some information at the bottom of my question, to indicate that it is already in a closure (item 1 on your list), still it smells pretty much like global, just script-scoped. Same applies to item 3. I like number 2 because the reality is that the script depends on particular DOM layout anyway, so keeping this with the DOM makes sense. I would like to clarify the sequence of events for you so that we could address item 4. What is the best way for me to do that?

Comment: I have added the sequence of events to the question.